# modding dwarf fortress adventure dwarves

Tags: dwarf-fortress, cheats, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I'm new to cheating in dwarf fortress, and have no idea how to mod my dwarf fortress adventure mode dwarf. I know he should be in the save folder, in region1. However, all that I find there is .dat files with no names referring to my character in any way. All of the .text files in raw are also very unhepful. Where do I go?

All i want to do is change some skill levels, and to remove the need for food/water, and be able to gain special bonuses like becoming a vampire/necromancer. How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

Find the file "creature_standard.txt" in the DF directory, and then look inside it for the Creature:Dwarf section. Now edit all of the racial stats for dwarves to something like the following:

```
[NATURAL_SKILL:AXE:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:SWORD:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:DAGGER:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:MACE:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:HAMMER:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:SPEAR:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:CROSSBOW:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:SHIELD:16]
[NATURAL_SKILL:ARMOR:16]
```

You are editing the starting skills for all dwarves to 16, which is legendary. Now if you start an adventurer dwarf, he will start with those stat levels. Unfortunatly, if you fight another dwarf as an adventurer, he will have those stats as well.

There is a thread at http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=142595.0 that discusses making invulnerable adventurer creatures.